# Is it possible to use sessions on html.erb file on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Is it possible to use sessions on html.erb file? If so please can someone explain how to use session variables on html.erb files ?? I have session[:id] on my controller and I need to get that id on my html.erb so how can I do that please give me a solution for this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your view: `<%= session[:id] %>`

`<%= ... %>` will evaluate any statement available to the view_context.

The **=** sign after the **%** is very important because is evaluating the expression,